# How to fix CSS Overflow & Flex behavior?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I'm trying to add this simple navbar, but when I give Filters `display: flex;` these buttons actually align themselves in the window. I want them to have a static width and want to give them a horizontal scroll property. I tried doing, `overflow-x: scroll;` but didn't worked.

[image: view1]

And also when I give overflow-x property somehow my dropdowns are now opening inside that div with a scroll in vertical axis.

How can I make the navbar look like this?

[image: pic]

```js
import React from "react";
import style from "../styles/navbar.module.css";
import Select from "react-select";

const FilterBtn = (props) => {
  const options = [
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" },
  ];

  return (
    <>
      <div className={style.DropDown}>
        <Select options={options} placeholder={props.filterType}></Select>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const Navbar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={style.Container}>Inventory Inspector</div>
      <div className={style.Filters}>
        <FilterBtn filterType={"Price"} />
        <FilterBtn filterType={"Brand"} />
        <FilterBtn filterType={"Size"} />
        <FilterBtn filterType={"Type"} />
        <FilterBtn filterType={"Quantity"} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

`navbar.module.css`

```css
.Container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6.5vh;
  background-color: #eeeeee;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.3rem;
}
.Filters {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 6.5vh;
  background-color: #f87d7d;

  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.DropDown {
  margin: 0 0.2rem;
  width: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: If my understanding is right, you are asking about mobile sizes, specifically for iPhone XR size and instead of the scroll bars on the buttons, you want the buttons to be full-sized but the website to be scrollable? Because you must have scrollbars for the smaller displays or alternatively hide an element or maybe `display: grid;`. But, also give a reproducible code snippet.

Comment: Add `flex-shrink: 0` to the flex items. This will disable flex shrink, which is active by default.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if you want to scroll horizontally then you have to specify a `width` set. Only when your screen width is smaller than the specified width, then the scroll kicks in.